# How to make equalization div's height?

Tags: jquery, height, equals

How to make equalization div's height?

1st div has "auto" height via listed items

and 2nd div has only min-height now:

[image]

my bad jquery code:

```
$("#contentt").height($("#content").height());
```

and JsFiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/3b5q9/5/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include jquery to your jsfiddle. Your code actually works fine:

```
Frameworks & extensions: jquery-1.9.1
```

**DEMO**: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3b5q9/10/)